# session_status() issue first connection

Tags: php

I have a website where people can create an account and then log in to their account.

When I check log in's inputs (email and password), I use a file called `control_login.php`. Here is its code:

```
// -> some DB calls checking whether the user exists or not...
if(isset($user->email) && password_verify($_POST['password_login'],$user -> password)){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['auth'] = $user;
    $user_id = $_SESSION['auth']->id;
    echo "Loading your profile...";
    header("Refresh:2 ; url=http://www.someurl.com/account.php?id=$user_id");
    exit();
} 
else{     
    $errors_login['danger'] = "We couldn't find any account. Please try again";
}
```

If everything is fine, I start a session and redirect to `account.php`. If not, I display an error message.

This `account.php` file includes a specific function called `logged_only()` that starts a session when everything is fine or deny access if there is no session. Here is its code:

```
function logged_only(){
    if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE){ 
        session_start();
    } 
    if(!isset($_SESSION['auth'])){
        echo 'Access denied';
        header('Refresh:2 ; url=http://www.someurl.com');
        exit();
    }
}
```

Here is my issue: everything is working fine locally. On real life (i.e when using the website url), everything is working fine when using Internet Explorer.
But, I have the following issue when using Chrome or Firefox:

1. I open a browser, go to my website and log in for the first time
2. I get "Loading your profile" from `control_login.php` meaning it found the user
3. When arriving on `account.php`, I get the following 'Access denied' from my `logged_only()` function.
4. I am redirected to the main page
5. I log in for the second time
6. I can connect to my profile properly :( ...
7. There won't be any problem to log in as long as I don't close the browser.

I am kind of lost... Where is the problem coming from?

Thank you for your help!

Note: I don't use cookies at all for the present time.

Comment: For one thing, you're echoing above a header and that is considered as outputting before header (use error reporting and you'll see). Now, once the browser has been closed, the session might have gone with it; cache issue also.

Comment: @Fred -ii-  Thank you for the comment. When I use error_reporting(E_ALL), nothing is displayed... I echoed after the header and it doesn't change anything :(

Comment: You also need to "display" them (if any) - add `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` to your present E_ALL.

Comment: You should start the session on the top of every script, no matter if the user is logged in or not. In the case that you produce any output before session_start, you'll get an error.

Comment: @Fred -ii- ok... No error displayed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error:

It was all about the URL.

If you first connected to the website by typing someurl.com instead of **www**.someurl.com, it was failing and then automatically redirected to **www**.someurl.com due to `logged_only()`.

So it won't fail only if these **www** are present when submitting user's information...

So, for those who need that, here is the way to change any non-www to a www-based url. All you need is update your `htacess` as follow:

```
# Redirect non-www to www:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This way, all url will be with these **www**!